# Trying to work with Microsoft.Kinect namespace in Visual Studio C#

Tags: visual-studio-2012, namespaces, kinect

I can add

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;
```

to Visual Studio 2012. I can also find and add the reference to Microsoft.Kinect in References.

I can not add or find in References:

```
using Microsoft.Kinect.Nui;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Audio;
```

This code will not work with just the namespace Microsoft.Kinect added to my using section:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.Kinects[0];
```

So I'm assuming it's not as straightforward as everyone suggests. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have found an old tuturial or example for kinect. The `Runtime` class, the `Kinect.Nui` and `Kinect.Audio` namespaces have existed in older versions of the kinect sdk. In the current version of the SDK (1.8) the following code is equivalent to your code:

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;
KinectSensor sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find much out there and what I did find referenced Runtime and Microsoft.Research.Kinect. -so ya, old.

Comment: ImageResolution, and Imagetype is inaccessible due to its protection level....This does generate errors, is there a better way to code to exclude these so it doesn't generate errors?

Comment: I do not understand, what you want to achieve. Maybe [Starting to Develop with Kinect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj159883.aspx) is helpful.